# What is the typescript static type for done in passport.js?

Tags: typescript, passport.js

In passport.js there is a done function, what is the correct type to use for this?

For example,

```
passport.use(new HeaderAPIKeyStrategy(
      { header: 'Authorization', prefix: 'Api-Key ' },
      false,
      function(apikey: string, done: <<WHAT GOES HERE>> ) {
        User.findOne({ apikey: apikey }, function (err, user) {
          if (err) { return done(err); }
          if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
          return done(null, user);
        });
      }
    ));
```

What type replaces the 'WHAT GOES HERE' text ?

Comment: In a pinch you can always use `any`.

Comment: I see you're using `passport-headerapikey` which is already written in TypeScript, so your `@types` should work fine. What editor are you using? What is your `tsconfig.json` or `tsc` command-line?

Comment: Like how you have to import Request and Response from express to use them as types in a controller I would expect to have to import a Done type from passport. It doesn't have a Done export though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you're using `passport-headerapikey` which is a third-party extension to passport.js - fortunately that's already written in TypeScript.

But still, [make sure you're using the latest `@types` for passport.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/passport) anyway.

[Going by the public source code on GitHub](https://github.com/hydra-newmedia/passport-headerapikey/blob/master/src/Strategy.ts), the definition for `HeaderAPIKeyStrategy`'s constructor is:

```
constructor(
    header           : { header: string, prefix: string },
    passReqToCallback: boolean,
    verify           : (apiKey: string, verified: (err: Error | null, user?: Object, info?: Object) => void, req?: Request) => void
)
```

I see that the `verify` parameter's signature is quite a mouthful. I'm surprised they aren't using a `type x = y` statement to make it more readable.

But you can define your own:

```
type VerifiedUserOrErrorFunc = ( err: Error | null, user?: Object, info?: Object ) => void;
type VerifyCallback          = ( apiKey: string, verified: VerifiedUserOrErrorFunc, req?: Request ) => void;

// So the constructor would be:
/*
constructor(
    header           : { header: string, prefix: string },
    passReqToCallback: boolean,
    verify           : VerifyCallback
)
*/
```

So this should *just work*. Note that there is no `done` function. just a `verified` callback you invoke for all outcomes (error, not-found, success). Also note that unlike other `Strategy` objects for Passport.js,  `HeaderAPIKeyStrategy` does not seem to use async Promises (as the callbacks all return `void`).

```
type VerifiedUserOrErrorFunc = ( err: Error | null, user?: Object, info?: Object ) => void;
type VerifyCallback          = ( apiKey: string, verified: VerifiedUserOrErrorFunc, req?: Request ) => void;

const strategyVerifyCallback = function( apikey: string, verified: VerifiedUserOrErrorFunc, req?: Request ): void {
    
    User.findOne( { apikey: apikey }, function( err, user ) {
        if( err ) {
            verified( err );
        }
        else if( user ) {
            verified( /*err*/ null, user );
        }
        else {
            verified( new Error( "User not found" ) );
        }
    } );
};

const strategy = new HeaderAPIKeyStrategy(
    /* header           : */ { header: 'Authorization', prefix: 'Api-Key ' },
    /* passReqToCallback: */ false,
    /* verify           : */ strategyVeriyCallback
);

passport.use( strategy );
```

Comment: Your right, its nothing to do with done, so funny..